# C# loopless way to split string into multidimensional array or jagged array

Tags: c#, linq

How do I split a string into a multidimensional array or a jagged array without looping?
I saw a code snippet where someone was doing so with a file stream and I can't figure out how to make it work for my string.
My string is similar to `1:2;3:1;4:1` and can be split into `ID:Qty`.
Here is the code I saw:

```
string[][] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path)
    .Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
String s = "1:2;1:3;1:4";
String[][] f = s.Split( ';' ).Select( t => t.Split( ':' ) ).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
MyString.Split(';').Select(s => s.Split(':'))
```

That will give you an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`.  You can call `.ToArray()` if you *really* want to, but it's rarely worth it.

Comment: Your answer is good.  It leaves me one step short of completion - how do I get from <IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> to String[][]?

Comment: Do you really need a string[][]?  IEnumerable will do 90% of what you need, and converting to a real array before you need to is very bad for performance.  If you do, the only change you need to make is calling `.ToArray()` in the right places.  You might also consider if you could get by with an array of IEnumerable or an IEnumerable of arrays.