# Split String into jagged array looplessly

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq

I have the following string

```
 String s = "1:2,a;1:3,b;1:4";
```

I am able to divide the string into two level jagged array by following the example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507266/c-sharp-loopless-way-to-split-string-into-multidimensional-array-or-jagged-array) but I am not able to extend it to one more level to have one more splitter based on `,` to get output in `string[][][] f`

```
String[][] f = s.Split( ';' ).Select( t => t.Split( ':' ) ).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
String s = "1:2,a;1:3,b;1:4";

String[][][] f = s.Split(';').Select(t => t.Split(':').Select( e => e.Split(',') ).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

Nest, my pretties!

```
String[][][] fff = 
    s.Split(';').Select(
        t => t.Split(':').Select(
            u => u.Split(',')
        ).ToArray()
    ).ToArray();

String[][][][] ffff =
s.Split(';').Select(
    t => t.Split(':').Select(
        u => u.Split(',').Select(
            v => v.Split('.')
        ).ToArray()
    ).ToArray()
).ToArray();

String[][][][][] fffff =
s.Split(';').Select(
    t => t.Split(':').Select(
        u => u.Split(',').Select(
            v => v.Split('.').Select(
                w => w.Split('/')
            ).ToArray()
        ).ToArray()
    ).ToArray()
).ToArray();
```

---

As you can see, this gets worse and worse the more things you want to split on. There's no way to make this recursive and still get strongly-typed arrays out, but here's a function that will give you `Array`s - you just need to recursively check whether each element is a `string` or another `Array`:

```
static Array Split(string source, int start, params char[] args)
{
    var split = source.Split(args[start]);
    if (args.Length == start + 1)
        return split;
    return split.Select(s => Split(s, start + 1, args)).ToArray();
}

...

String s = "1:2,a;1:3,b;1:4";
Array array = Split(s, 0, ';', ':', ',');
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
s.Split( ';' ).Select(
    t => t.Split( ':' ).Select(
        u => u.Split( ',' )
    ).ToArray()
).ToArray();
```